# How can I forward/proxy requests done to an endpoint in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to make all requests under a path proxy to another host. I have my frontend code which is running on localhost's port 19988 making requests like `GET https://localhost:19988/something/1`, I need my spring backend to redirect those to `https://localhost:18896/something/1`, which is the other service which has that URL. I can not change the frontend code (in production both services run in the same url, so this works naturally, but in development I need to somehow proxy them.).

Basically I need to do exactly what [devServer.proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) does for webpack, but for a spring application.

I can not run a node/express proxy because springboot is already using the port 19988, how can I accomplish this?

I have tried adding this request mapping to one of my controllers, but it is not doing anything.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/something/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView method() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:https://localhost:18896/something/");
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check gateway from spring-boot-cloud

More information you can find [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway)

Or.. zuul proxy [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-with-zuul-proxy)

Comment: Does that mean that I have to install external libraries? Isn't there a simpler solution? The usecase is very specific and very small, I'd like to do it without any library/external package.

Comment: When you use framework like sprint-boot you have just out of the box solutions, so why waste time writing your own code?

Comment: I tihnk the best way is put some proxy service between web and real service.. e.g. zuul gives you full control for all requests just like that